# How to fix the gensim mallet issue?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, topic-modeling

I am trying to use mallet model using gensim. when i tried to use below code i am getting error. please help me out from this.

```
import os
os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'F:\Suneel\Venkat Freelancing\Topic Modeling\new mallet\mallet-2.0.8\'})
mallet_path = 'F:/Suneel/Venkat Freelancing/Topic Modeling/new mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet' # update this path
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
```

error:
CalledProcessError: Command 'F:/Suneel/Venkat Freelancing/Topic Modeling/new mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\921f3_corpus.txt --output C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\921f3_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Just after getting the error (so that any necessary temp files are still in the same places), what happens if you try the exact same command-line, `F:/Suneel/Venkat Freelancing/Topic Modeling/new mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\921f3_corpus.txt --output C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\921f3_corpus.mallet`? (It may show more useful error info, that, if corrected, will also allow it to work from within Gensim.)

Comment: But also, note that all such `wrapper` functionality has been removed from the latest release of Gensim - so you may want to use the `mallet-2.0.8` too separately, via its own interfaces, rather than rely on now-unsupported Gensim wrapping code.